# Android: time picker in a dialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, time, dialog

I tried to modify [this](https://github.com/IvanKovac/TimePickerWithSeconds) `time picker` I found here on stackoverflow  and placed it in a `dialog` in my `application`. When I try to pick the `time` the result is not what I setted but it is the time of the device, so the time isn't set well. The `function` TimeSetting is used to call the time picker.
 I tryed to make it start from zero and take the right time but with no result. Can someone help me find out where the error is?
 
here is the ExampleDialog.java file:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;
import com.ikovac.timepickerwithseconds.MyTimePickerDialog;
import com.ikovac.timepickerwithseconds.TimePicker;
import java.util.Calendar;

    public class ExampleDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    private EditText textInputNome;
    private ExampleDialogListener listener;
    private Button positiveButton;
    private TextView text_view_timesec;
    private Button SetTimeBTN;
    private String nome = null;
    private int timeInSeconds=-1;
    private int hourOfDay;
    private int minute;
    private int seconds;


    /*for MainActivity*/
    public interface ExampleDialogListener {
        boolean applyProgram(String nome);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);
        textInputNome = view.findViewById(R.id.tiCrea);
        SetTimeBTN=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_SetTime);
        text_view_timesec=view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
      textInputNome.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                TimeSetting();
            }
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                nome =textInputNome.getText().toString().trim();
                TimeSetting();
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                TimeSetting();
            }
        });

        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setTitle("Nome programma");
        builder.setNegativeButton("delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            }
        });
            builder.setPositiveButton("create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                String nome = textInputNome.getText().toString().trim();
                listener.applyProgram(nome);
            }
        });
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;



    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            listener = (ExampleDialogListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() +
                    "must implement ExampleDialogListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }      
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog) getDialog();

        if (d != null ) {
            positiveButton = d.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
private void TimeSetting(){
        SetTimeBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Btn clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                MyTimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new MyTimePickerDialog(getContext(), new MyTimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int seconds) {
                        SetTimeBTN.setText(getString(R.string.time) + String.format("%02d", hourOfDay) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minute) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                    }
                    }, hourOfDay=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), seconds=c.get(Calendar.SECOND), true);

                timeInSeconds = ((hourOfDay * 60 * 60) + (minute * 60) + seconds);
                text_view_timesec.setText("hh=" + hourOfDay + " mm=" + minute + " ss=" + seconds + " time tot=" + timeInSeconds);
                positiveButton.setEnabled(!nome.isEmpty() && timeInSeconds > 0);

                mTimePicker.show();
            }
           });
    }
}
```

Here is the xml of the dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/time_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tiCrea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_SetTime"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="186dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clickToSetTime"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:gravity="start" />
    

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="here is the time setted from the timepkr" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate method change this two lines

```
 final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);
```

to

```
final LinearLayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, (ViewGroup)R.id.time_view");//here the id of the root LinearLayout in the XMl File layout_dialog.
```

Comment: I tried but there are two errors: `cannot resolve LinearLayoutInflater` in the first line, and in the second one on ViewGroup: `Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'int' to 'android.view.ViewGroup' `. There is an error also on .inflate due to the first one i think